# Insert new line after non matching pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have following output from script

```
host1:101
host1:102
host2:101
host2:102
host2:103
host4:101
host5:101
host5:102
host5:103
host5:104
```

etc..

I wanted to insert a new line after each host group.

```
host1:101
host1:102

host2:101
host2:102

host3:101
host3:102
```

Any AWK onliners to compare each consecute line with 1st field and insert new line before non-matching 1st field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 awk -F: '{if (NR>1 && save!=$1) print "";} {save=$1; print;}'
```

You never want to insert a blank line before line 1,
so don't even think about it unless `NR>1`. 
Thereafter, print the blank line if the first field
is not the saved value from the previous line.

Comment: @sudobash: If you believe that this is the best answer (or the clearest, best-explained answer, or the first posted among comparably good answers), you can ***"accept"*** it by clicking on the green check mark to the left.

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk`:

```
awk -F: 'a!~$1{print x}a=$1' file
```

Remove first blank line of output

```
awk -F: 'a&&a!~$1{print x}a=$1' file
```

Comment: +1: Though better to add `awk -F: 'a!~$1 && NR>1{print x}a=$1' file` to prevent the empty first line.

Comment: @jaypal in hindsight could also have done `awk -F: 'a&&a!~$1{print x}a=$1' file`

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`:

```
$ awk -F':' 'FNR > 1 && p != $1 {printf "\n"};{p = $1}1' file
host1:101
host1:102

host2:101
host2:102
host2:103

host4:101

host5:101
host5:102
host5:103
host5:104
```

Answer (score 1):

One more awk approach:

```
awk -F ':' '!a[$1]++ && NR>1{print ""}1' file
```